# No signal to external monitor until after login (Mac Mini 2018)

Tags: display, mac-mini, hdmi

I have a mac mini 2018.  My old apple monitor (connected via USB-C using a USB-C-to-thunderbolt adaptor) worked fine but eventually died.  Then I bought a new monitor that connects via HDMI.  It works fine once I'm logged in but it gets no signal when the login screen is displayed.

I'm using the HDMI cable that came with the monitor, and it works fine when plugged into another computer, so I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with the mac mini.

Is there some kind of display setting for bootup/login that could be messed up? Perhaps one that got set from the previous monitor but no longer works for the current one?

Thanks in advance for any ideas!